# SSRF Vulnerability while calling REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, veracode

I am using a method where it calls another REST API to retrieve an ID from the DB. When I run the veracode scan for the class I am getting Security flaw "Server-side Request Forgery" at below line.

```
response =  resttemplate.getForEntity(resturl, String.class);
```

Not sure How to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated. Below is my full code for that method.

```
public static String getIDFromDB(String resturl) {

  String id = null;
  RestTemplate resttemplate = new RestTemplate();
  ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<>(HTTPStatus.OK)
  try {
        response =  resttemplate.getForEntity(resturl, String.class);
        if (response.getStatusCode == HTTPStatus.OK && response.getBody.trim() != null) {
        id = response.getBody.trim() ;
      }
  } Catch(Exception e) {
     log.error("failed to get msgID: {}", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are allowing in your code to pass the resturl completely in your code, so it enables the attacker to bypass and route the URL to their intended destination.

To avoid this, so should externalise and refer the URL having domain and the application contexts with operation name in config files or dB

Comment: thanks for your response. In this project we cannot have the properties or any config files. Moreover we have different urls for different environments. Is there any way to sanitize the url ?

Comment: Try breaking the URL and pas them as separate tokens in your method and then concat